# How to pass global context to anonymous block in javascript using strict mode

Tags: javascript, variables, global, anonymous, strict

I want to use a global variable in my anonymous block

```
function(foo){
 'use strict';
 bar(foo)
})(window)
```

window will not work. Because of the strict settings and other quality controls.

Comment: Of course it will work: `(function(foo) { 'use strict'; bar(foo) })(window)`

Comment: You mean `bar` is global and you want to pass `window` to it?

Comment: no, foo is some global variable. it is about window not being accepted because it's not declared

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble finding the answer to this question, so I thought I document it here for prosperity.

```
function(globals){ 
  'use strict'; 
  bar(globals.foo);
})(this)
```

I hope this is useful to someone...